# Как реализовать "Производители-Потребители" где один производитель и несколько потребителей получающих одни и те-же данные?

Tags: java, многопоточность, очередь, exchange, consumer

Пытаюсь реализовать задачу "Производители-Потребители" на BlockingQueue при следующих условиях:

Один производитель (Читаю непрерывные данные с датчика веса  из ком порта)

И несколько потребителей:

1. получает сырые данные и отправляет из отрисовывать на график JavaFX
2. получает сырые данные, фильтрует их скользящим усреднением и отправляет из отрисовывать на график JavaFX
3. получает сырые данные, фильтрует их скользящим усреднением, и на основе полученных данных рассчитываю некоторый коэффициент и записываю его в ком порт.

Все в отдельных потоках.
**Все потребители в моем случае должны получать одно и тоже значение пришедшее от производителя.**
Как это правильно реализовать?

Стоит ли мне создавать 3 разных очереди в которые производитель будет записывать прочитанное из ком-порта значение или есть более элегантное решение?

Подумал про Exchanger, но если я правильно понял , метод exchange работает только для 2ух (пары) потоков.

Comment: "Стоит ли мне создавать 3 разных очереди в которые производитель будет записывать прочитанное из ком-порта значение" - ДА. "или есть более элегантное решение?" - НЕТ

Comment: Александр, спасибо за ответ.

Answer (score 0):

> Стоит ли мне создавать 3 разных очереди в которые производитель будет записывать прочитанное из ком-порта значение или есть более элегантное решение?

Можно и так. Или как вариант добавить одного "супер потребителя", который делегирует вызов остальным трём, но тут есть нюансы. Так что лучше сделать как вы написали - будет надёжнее.